# Xcode 6.1.1 auto write strange code into header files

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm a new bie with Swift and just start with the first project on Xcode 6.1.1 (I run mac 10.9.5 on a PC).
After creating a new project, I get that error message when click on Main.Storyboard:

**Interface Builder was unable to determine the type of "Main.storyboard"**

Then I show the code behind of the Main.Storyboard and found the strange code: **utf-8;1342179841.0**

```
utf-8;1342179841.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="6211" systemVersion="14A298i" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" initialViewController="BYZ-38-t0r">
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="6204"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="y3c-jy-aDJ"/>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="wfy-db-euE"/>
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="600"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
```

After checking other files I have the same problem at the beginning of the files:

**utf-8;1342179841.0**

So what wrong with my Xcode or my system environment? Can you pls tell me how to fix that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Can you add new interface and check the new file too. Also there are some problems with your Xcode version, please install latest version of it.

Latest version is Xcode 6.3.2 for now.

https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/

Comment: I solved the problem. Cause I saved the project into NTFS format :)